# clickhouse python stream query hangs

Tags: clickhouse

I need to stream data which is around 50GB. I've been trying to stream this using clickhouse's `query_df_stream`:

```py
import clickhouse_connect
import time

def pub(queue: queue.Queue):
  client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(
    host="localhost",
    port=8123,
    connect_timeout=100,
    send_receive_timeout=1800 
  )
  with client.query_df_stream("select * from data", 
                              settings={"session_check": True, "session_timeout":1800}
                             ) as df_stream: 
    for df in df_stream: # code seems to hang here
      for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if queue.qsize() > 10000:
          time.sleep(1)
        queue.put(row)
    queue.put(DONE)

def sub(queue):
  while True:
    row = queue.get()
    if row == DONE:
      return
    #  <do something for a long time>
```

I initially thought it was a timeout error so I tried adding `session_timeout` setting to `query_df_stream` but that did not work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
**If I do not limit the size of the queue, then it works fine**, but I can't do that due to memory constraints.
I tried using `query_row_block_stream` and got this error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/myproject/test.py", line 116, in _receive_data
    for block in stream:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_connect/driver/common.py", line 196, in __next__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_connect/driver/query.py", line 260, in _row_block_stream
    for block in self._column_block_stream():
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_connect/driver/transform.py", line 69, in gen
    next_block = get_block()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_connect/driver/transform.py", line 57, in get_block
    raise StreamFailureError(message) from None
clickhouse_connect.driver.exceptions.StreamFailureError
```

EDIT2:
restricting the blocksize to be the same size as the queue works, but it doesn't solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with

```
client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(send_progress=False, compress='lz4')
```

There was an issue where zstd would cause the whole response to be compresed and sent as a single frame - https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect/issues/122#issuecomment-1426323030

Comment: This was addressed, so confirm your version also https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect/issues/122#issuecomment-1426877977

Comment: Also possible, https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect/issues/157

Comment: Can you also check with just a standard Python stream using the `query_row_block_stream` instead of `query_df_stream`?  That might narrow down the problem to dataframes.

Comment: I tried both but did not work, i updated an error message.